# What is the opposite of "sparsity" in a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

If a sparse matrix has only 1% non-zero entries, I find it weird to speak of "1% sparsity". In particular, "increasing sparsity" goes along with a smaller percentage of non-zero entries, so this is determined to cause confusion. However, I have never read about a matrix with "99% sparsity", expressing that the matrix has 1% non-zero entries. The number of non-zero entries seems to be what's used to characterize a sparse matrix.

So which word to use? The dictionary proposes "density", but that may sound odd. A sparse matrix with 1% density? Sure, if there's nothing better. Or is there?

*Non-subjective variant of my question:* What are terms used by other authors for the fraction of non-zero entries in a sparse matrix?

Comment: Sounds subjective

Comment: Density is a physics concept. That's not subjective, is it? In the extreme case it is "numbers of particles per unit of volume". Number of particles is a discrete amount just as elements in a matrix are.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix <-- has "density" in parenthesis after sparsity but I haven't seen it written in many contexts.